# TypeError: Cannot read property '#' of undefined In simple JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm making a small battleship game with a friend of mine.  We thought it would be good practice as we learned.  We have a two dimensional array that is 10X10 all filled with zeros.  We will change those zeros to ones in the places our ships will go.  I made a function to place a 1X5 ship down.  The function prompts the user for two coordinates and assigns those to variables that are outside of the function.  It gets the coordinates of the start point and asks for the direction the player wants the rest wrest of the ship to go.  If there are no obstacles the ship should be placed.  If there are some the function should restart. The thing is I get this error.  The # is replaced by the number in the prompt asking for the vertical coordinate position.

Here is the error.
TypeError: Cannot read property '#' of undefined In Battleship Game

Here is the Function

```
function firstShip(){
    window.alert("We will be placing your 1 by 5 length ship.  Take note that you are playing on a 10 by 10 board.");
    userX = parseInt(prompt("Horizontal Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship")-1);
    userY = parseInt(prompt("Vertical Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship")-1);
    direction = prompt("Now choose the direction you want the rest of your ship to face.  You may   use the words up, down left, or right.").toLowerCase(); 

    //Making sure the ship will fit and nothing is already there!
    if ((userX+4)>9 && direction=== "right"){
     window.alert("You are too close to the right edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
     firstShip();
    }
    else if ((userX-4)<0 && direction=== "left"){
     window.alert("You are too close to the left edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
     firstShip();
    }
    else if ((userY+4)>9 && direction=== "down"){
     window.alert("You are too close to the bottom edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
     firstShip();
    }
    else if ((userY-4)<0 && direction=== "up"){
     window.alert("You are too close to the top edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
     firstShip();
    }
    else if (user[userX][userY] === 1) {
        window.alert("Coordinate already used. Please try again");
        firstShip();
    } 

    else if (user[userX][userY] === null || user[userX][userY] === ""){
        window.alert("That coordinate isn't on the board. Restarting...");
        firstShip();
    }

    else if(direction !=="up" || direction !=="down" || direction !=="left" || direction !=="right") {
        for(i=1; i<5; i++){
            if(user[userX+i][userY] === 1 && direction=== "right"){
                window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                isThere=true;
            }
            if(user[userX-i][userY] === 1 && direction=== "left"){
                window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                isThere=true;
            }
            if(user[userX][userY+i] === 1 && direction=== "down"){
                window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                isThere=true;
            }
            if(user[userX][userY-i] === 1 && direction=== "up"){
                window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                isThere=true;
            }
            if(isThere===true){
                isThere = false;
                firstShip(); 
                return false;
            }
            else{
                user[userX][userY] = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        window.alert("Sorry but you didn't type in the direction you wanted your ship to go correctly. Restarting...");
        firstShip();
    }


    // Building Ship 1x5
    for(i=1; i<4; i++){

        if (direction==="up"){
            user[userX][userY-i] =1;
        }
        else if (direction==="down"){
            user[userX][userY+i] =1;
        }
        else if (direction==="left"){
            user[userX-i][userY] =1;
        }
        else if (direction==="right"){
            user[userX][userY+i] =1;
        }
    }
}
firstShip();
//Here is the new cpu creation. There may be a way to shorten the if statements, but other than that, its all set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a negative array index.

If you try the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/g4i1QAY6COU18XTK6QZI?p=preview

and enter 1, 1, right for the answers to the questions, you will see that you get an error on line 28 of script.js:

```
if(user[userX-i][userY] === 1 && direction=== "left"){
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What happens is that userX = 0 and i = 1, so we are evaluating `user[-1][0]`.  Since user[-1] is undefined, that's why you're seeing that error.

Comment: please create a fiddle or plnkr of your new code, and let me know what new error you are seeing

Comment: I put the code here http://plnkr.co/edit/WiRuqdakLBiC4F6YIwiX?p=linter and get this error. I fixed it so that it should never run negatives numbers too in the array. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: yeah I was just gonna post you still have negative numbers: http://plnkr.co/edit/zoH2wbUf8rsk2WUnLnNO?p=preview

Comment: very nice, that's satisfying.  now that you've got it working, you might want to look into refactoring your code.  there's a lot of duplication, and you could get rid of most if not all of those if statements with a different model of the problem.

Comment: Good suggestion but I plan on cleaning things up when I succeed in finishing the whole game.  I'm wrestling with another problem now that involves how to link different div tags with different slots in the array.  I'm trying to display the placement of the ships on the screen.  The thing is the only idea I've got is giving each div a seperate id or class.  that would be painful making 200 classes or ids for the 200 boxes on screen.  And even then I'd have to figure out how to link the ids to the slots of the array.

Comment: this might be helpful for the problem: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp.  You wouldn't have to give ids to every single div that way.

Comment: how would I link the divs to slots of the array?  I want to do this so that  for example when a ship is hit it can access the div corresponding to it and, it changes the color of the div.  This is what I have so far for the page layout. http://zachooz.github.io/Code-Projects/Battleship.html

Comment: I know if I give them all an id I could do document.getElementById("p2").style.backgroundColor="blue";

Comment: Simple proof of concept here: http://jsbin.com/iyiyoz/1/edit.  Of course you can, and probably should, construct the divs themselves using javascript, but I thought this was a clearer way of demonstrating the idea.

Comment: Wow thanks.  My divs were constructed of html.  I'll have to change my code.

Comment: I'll use that but I don't know jquery yet so maybe I'll understand how you did that in the future.

Comment: You don't need jquery: http://jsbin.com/iyiyoz/2/edit.  It's just a little more verbose without out.

Comment: I really appreciate your help by the way and one last question how would I each box to separate part of the array without doing it the hard way.  What you have now looks like it treats all the divs as the same.  I have an two dimensional array mirroring the board except a player specifies where he wants to place his ships.  It goes to the array but how would I link that so that the corresponding coordinate show up on the board of divs.